# Chrome (Brave) browser--Allow redirects for a certain website

Tags: google-chrome, brave

How do I let Brave browser redirect and allow pop-ups for a particular website? Let's say we want popups and redirects at `https://example.com/`.

Comment: I read the similar questions that Superuser presented while I was typing. None of them quite matched the question I'm asking. My Q is on topic and very specific. It shouldn't be penalized for its brevity.

Comment: What's very specific here? All I see is 2 sentences. And I'm not even sure for which browser you need the answer as title/tags speak about both, but content onl mentions Brave.

Comment: The issue may be that the query seems like something that would already be part of a FAQ document or already answered elsewhere.  In  [How do I ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Tell%20us%20what%20you%20found%20and%20why%20it%20didn%E2%80%99t%20meet%20your%20needs) there is a note to *"thoroughly searched for an answer"* and also *"tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs."*

Answer (score 2):

you can use tampermonkey chrome extension to do that,
here is script :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         redirect at certain website
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http*://*example.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // URL target
    let redirect_to_url=`https://www.github.com`
setTimeout(function () {
    alert(`popup message: redirect`)
    let f;
        if (confirm(`redirect to[${redirect_to_url}]\n confirm?`)) {
            f= true;
        } else {
            f= false;
        }
        if(f){
            // GM_openInTab(b, { active: true, insert: true, setParent :true })
            // jump in place
            location.href=redirect_to_url;
        }else{
        }
},1000); // after 1 second ,the script begin to work

})();
```